# Can an isomorphism induce a differentiable manifold structure

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I was thinking If defining a map from one topological space X to a set Y can induce topology on the set Y and make it a topological space then can the same be said for manifolds ? especially if i have an isomorphism between a space that has a manifold structure and a space that's unknown, can i say it will have a manifold structure? and will be of the same class, for example if X is isomorphic to Y and X has a differentiable manifold then will Y have a differentiable manifold structure as well?

Comment: Does isomorphic here mean homeomorphic as topological spaces or a bijection between sets?

Comment: Yes, in the sense that if $\phi:X \to Y$ is a _bijection_ and $X$ has the structure of a smooth manifold, then $Y$ acquires the structure of a smooth manifold if we define a subset $V \subset Y$ to be open if and only if $U:=\phi^{-1}(V) \subset X$ is open, and we define a mapping $f$ on an open set $V$ to be smooth if and only if $f\circ\phi$ is smooth on $U$.

Comment: @Thorgott I am not sure but both homeomorphisms and bijections preserve structures on sets. So why does it make a difference ?

Comment: Because in one case it makes sense to ask for compatibility of the manifold structure with the given topology, in the other case it does not. The answer is positive in any case, but it is not clear which scenario precisely you're inquiring about.

Comment: @Thorgott I am inquiring about homeomorphisms

Comment: This is a phenomenon known as [transport of structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure).